# How to exit VB6 application with and set exit code

Tags: vb6, exit, exit-code

I have a VB6 appliacation and I need to exit from the application and set the ExitCode.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't really.  At least not safely.  See [PRB: Call to ExitProcess() from Visual Basic Application Hinders Process Exit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288216)

> One particular instance in which a call to ExitProcess() is known to cause a problem involves COM objects. If a Visual Basic application has an outstanding reference to an out-of-process COM object when it calls ExitProcess(), the calling process is likely to "hang" or cause an access violation. A direct call to CoUninitialize() immediately before the call to ExitProcess() will usually prevent this problem. Although this approach allows you to work around the problem, it is not recommended or supported by Microsoft.
>
> The only advantage that would arise out of calling ExitProcess() from a Visual Basic application is the ability to set an exit code for the process. But because of the unpredictable nature of calling ExitProcess() from Visual Basic, it is better to communicate the success or failure of the process through some other means, such as writing an exit code to a file or sending a windows message to another process.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest to invent a different way of communicating with the calling process or command line.

But you *could* use Karl Peterson's [method of creating a console app](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/Console/) from VB6? Then use `Con.ExitCode = 1` (as shown in the second sample).

He's distributing a free add-in [vbAdvance](http://vb.mvps.org/tools/vbAdvance) that helps you build console apps.

Disclaimer: adapted from my answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063843/does-the-api-call-exitprocess-work-ok-in-vb6-if-you-follow-the-ms-caveats/3065048#3065048)

Comment: His `Con.ExitCode` is an example of what you should *not* do.  To be as safe as possible you must make sure all objects have been released before exiting `Sub Main` and at its very end you have to call ExitProcess() using a typelib definition and not a `Declare Function`.

Comment: The links are dead :(